Volume growth of a ball in a Riemannian manifold
Let $\left(M,g\right)$ be a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold. Suppose at a given point $p\in M$, the volume of the ball $\operatorname{B}\left(p,r\right)$ satisfies the following inequality:
$$
\liminf_{r \to \infty}
{\operatorname{Vol}\left(\,\operatorname {B}\left(\,p,r\,\right)\,\right)\over r^{k}} > 0,\quad
\mbox{for some fixed integer}\ k > 0
$$

Then does the above inequality hold at all the points of the $\mbox{manifold ?}$.
In the literature, the notion of polynomial volume growth does not depend on the point.
But I am confused if this notion is defined only at a particular point, then does it holds for all points ?.

Please help me.

$Vol(B(q,r)) \geq Vol(B(p, r-d)$,where $d$ is the distance between $p,q$.

$Vol(B(q,r)) \geq Vol(B(p, r-d)$,where $d$ is the distance between $p,q$.
Therefore
${ Vol(B(q,r))\over r^d} \geq {Vol(B(p, r-d)\over (r-d)^k}\times {r^d\over (r-d)^k}$
and the result.
